# Flexslider WP plugin on blackberry playbook

Tags: flexslider, blackberry-playbook

I'm using Flexslider for an image gallery on a mobile website, we're targeting basically every tablet under the moon and the galleries prev/next buttons fail on the blackberry playbook, also image swiping doesn't work (but I've given up on that). swiping and prev/next work on ipads and androids tablets so I know it's working properly, just not on the playbook. If anyone has any ideas why this is happening only on the playbook and/or a fix to it I'd be a super happy person :)